# Search for orders that have two products, one with specific reference, other with specific description

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a SQL query issue that seems easy to fix but I can't figure out how to make it work..

I basically have two tables : Orders, and OrderDetails... Each order have several products, registered in OrderDetails table.
I want to be able to find all the orders that have 2 products ; one with a specific reference, and the other with a specific description.

Here is the query I wrote:

```
SELECT
  o.orderNumber

FROM
  `order` AS o

JOIN
  `orderDetail` AS d ON o.id = d.orderID

WHERE
  d.reference = "F40" AND 
  d.description = "Epee"
```

Here is the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd94e/1

The query is returning 0 reccord, and it should return order number QQ00000QQ

Can someone please explain to me how can I make that query work?? Thank you very much!!

Comment: your `orderDetail` table does not have an entry that fulfills both where conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to find an order that has one orderline satisfying a condition (reference = "F40") and another orderline satisfying another condition (description = "Epee").

Doing a single join will not solve this, as you will be searching for one orderline that satisfies both conditions. You should do something like this instead:

```
SELECT orderNumber FROM `order`
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT orderid FROM orderDetail od1
    INNER JOIN orderDetail od2
    USING (orderid)
    WHERE od1.reference = 'F40' AND od2.description = "Epee"
)
```

Comment: Yes, I have updated my answer so it does not use INTERSECT accordingly :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you must a create an field same. 
example in : `order` = id_order
`orderDetail` = id_order

Then if you want to find all, you must insert that id_order same. 
example :

```
INSERT INTO `order`
(id_order , orderNumber)
VALUES
('1','QQ00000QQ'),
('2','AA11111AA'),
('3','LO00000OL'),
('4','AA12345BB');


INSERT INTO `orderDetail`
(orderID, reference, description,id_order)
VALUES
(1, 'F40', 'Wire','1'),
(1, 'Q25', 'Epee','1'),
(1, 'Z99', 'Mask','1'),
(2, 'F40', 'Wire','2'),
(3, 'Q25', 'Epee','2'),
(4, 'F40', 'Wire','4'),
(4, 'Z99', 'Mask','3');

SELECT
  o.orderNumber

FROM
  `order` AS o

JOIN
  `orderDetail` AS d ON o.id = d.orderID

WHERE
  d.reference = '4'

GROUP BY
  o.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query isn't matching your data. There are no records that match `d.reference = "F40"` **AND** `d.description = "Epee"`.

If you want to return order number QQ00000QQ then you need

```
SELECT
  o.orderNumber

FROM
  `order` AS o

JOIN
  `orderDetail` AS d ON o.id = d.orderID

WHERE
  d.reference = "F40" AND 
  d.description = "Wire" //Note change to condition
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the problem ; I am looking for an order that have TWO products : Product number 1, which has "F40" as a reference, AND Product number 2 which has "Epee" as a description. I want to find all orders that contain those two products ; not the orders that just contain "F40" / "Wire" product.

Comment: Yes, so i have. In that case, the answer from Dan is correct.