# SQL Server - Find all customers who've placed two types of orders

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to pull a list of all open orders from a customer where the same customer has used both one of our special payment types as well as one of our standard options. Specifically, those that have open orders with **either** prepay or 10n30 **and** at least one normal order. So, in the example tables below I would want to return `order_id` 1, 3, and 4.

```
cust_orders                       order_info
+----------+-----------+          +----------+-------------+----------+
| cust_id  | order_id  |          | order_id |  pay_type   |  status  |
+----------+-----------+          +----------+-------------+----------+
|       1  |         1 |          |       1  | standard    | open     |
|       1  |         2 |          |       2  | prepay      | closed   |
|       1  |         3 |          |       3  | prepay      | open     |
|       1  |         4 |          |       4  | 10n30       | open     |
|       2  |         5 |          |       5  | standard    | deferred |
|       2  |         6 |          |       6  | prepay      | open     |
|       3  |         7 |          |       7  | N/A         | deferred |
|       4  |         8 |          |       8  | prepay      | open     |
|       4  |         9 |          |       9  | standard    | closed   |
|       4  |        10 |          |      10  | prepay      | open     |
+----------+-----------+          +----------+-------------+----------+
```

I have the following query

```
SELECT *
FROM cust_orders AS co
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT *
              FROM order_info
              WHERE pay_type IN('prepay', '10n30')
              AND status = 'open' ) AS o1 on o1.order_id = co.order_id
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT *
              FROM order_info
              WHERE pay_type NOT IN('prepay', '10n30')
              AND status = 'open' ) AS o2 on o2.order_id = co.order_id
WHERE o1.order_id IS NOT NULL
     AND o2.order_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY co.order_id DESC;
```

but it runs very slowly and returns a bunch of duplicates.

I've looked at [Search for orders that have two products, one with specific reference, other with specific description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154448/) and [SELECT all orders with more than one item and check all items status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14052456/) but neither seems to be what I need.

---

EDIT: Thanks to gjvdkamp for the basis to the code below; I modified their solution to use in a larger query and everything runs fine now.

```
SELECT co.*, [other fields]
FROM cust_order AS co
     LEFT JOIN [other tables]
WHERE cust_id IN ( SELECT co.cust_id
                   FROM cust_order AS co
                        LEFT JOIN order_info o on o.order_id = co.order_id
                   WHERE o.status = 'open'
                   GROUP BY co.cust_id
                   HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN o.pay_type IN ('prepay', '10n30') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 
                      AND SUM(CASE WHEN (o.pay_type NOT IN ('prepay', '10n30') OR o.pay_type IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 'handrolled pivot' would work well here:

```
select cust_id,
       sum(case when pay_type = 'normal'             then 1 else 0 end) as NormalCount,
       sum(case when pay_type in ('prepay', '10n30') then 1 else 0 end) as OtherCount
from   cust_order co 
       inner join order o on co.order_id = o.order_id 
where  o.status = 'open'
       and o.pay_type in ('normal','prepay','10n30')
group by cust_id
having NormalCount> 0 and 
       OtherCount > 0
```

This would only require a single join (merge if you have you indexes right) and then aggregegates that. Don't know the statistics on your orders table but added where statement on pay_type for good measure. This would be hard to beat speed wise..

Edit: removed the with statement as it's not even needed

Comment: I changed it up a bit to use in a larger query posted in the edit above; this worked well, thank you.

Comment: @5E4ME . . . This doesn't pull *open orders* which is what your question asks for.  I don't understand why you accepted it.

Comment: where  o.status = 'open'

Answer (score 1):

I think some window functions do the trick:

```
select o.*
from (select o.*,
             sum(case when o.pay_type in ('prepay', '10n30') then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by co.cust_id) as num_special,
             sum(case when o.pay_type in ('standard') then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by co.cust_id) as num_standard
      from cust_orders co join
           order_info o
           on co.orderid = o.order_id
      where o.status = 'open' 
     ) o
where num_standard > 0 and
      num_special > 0;
```

Comment: Running as-is gives me an ambiguous column error on cust_id in the case statements. Relabeling it as either o.cust_id or co.cust_id yields no results